# influxdb - some values become null when request with mean() or median()

Tags: influxdb

i have an issue with `influxdb` query.
when I query normally:

```
SELECT "distance" FROM "testdb"."autogen"."laserdistance" WHERE time > timeA AND time < timeB
```

I will get back all the data without error.

if I query with either `mean()` or `median()`:

```
SELECT mean("distance") AS "mean_distance" FROM "testdb"."autogen"."laserdistance" WHERE time > timeA AND time < timeB GROUP BY time(some_interval) FILL(null)
```

I will sure get back some `null` value in a very inconsistent pattern(sometime a lot, sometime not so much).

I understand that `FILL(null)` is the one responsible for the `null` issue to fill in the interval that don't have value.

is there a way to get the nearest value instead of fill it with null?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FILL(linear)`:

> linear - Reports the results of linear interpolation for time intervals with no data.

Doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.7/query_language/data_exploration/#group-by-time-intervals-and-fill